# Swagger: How do you add ApiModelProperty for 3rd party code?

Tags: java, swagger, openapi

I've got a Java project using Swagger. It does a great job of generating the swagger.json, but it's listing all the output fields as optional and I need some of them to be required. That's not a problem for my code because I can add the @ApiModelProperty annotation and specify whether it's required.

The problem is with objects from 3rd party jars. I can't go annotate that code. How do I create the equivalent functionality of @ApiModelProperty on 3rd party code?

Comment: The workaround will be extend the class, annotate it and use that extended class. It is not a solution a workaround if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume we're talking about newer version of swagger / openAPI. You can kludge this with a `ReaderListener`, something like so:

```java
    public static class FixSwagger implements ReaderListener {
        @Override
        public void beforeScan(OpenApiReader reader, OpenAPI openAPI) {}

        @Override
        public void afterScan(OpenApiReader reader, OpenAPI openAPI) {
            var paths = openAPI.getPaths();
            paths.remove("/application.wadl");
            paths.remove("/application.wadl/{path}");
        }
    }
```

And then register this in your code using: `jersey.register(FixSwagger.class);`

The `beforeScan()` and `afterScan()` methods allow you to mutate the `openAPI` object, so you can programatically change whatever you need to.